# Quando passado por class, números não sai aleatórios

Tags: python, classes, random, redes-neurais

Estou criando uma rede neural, e agora estou fazendo a parte que criaria a população para ser treinada, mas não estou conseguindo obter uma aleatoriedade. Encontrei o problema só não o compreendo e não sei como contorna.
(tirando a gambiarra que seria de passar uma função fora da class pra modificar os valor)

o seguinte codigo exemplifica o erro:

```
import random as rd

# Criar 10 numeros aleatorios

# 10 random normal
for i in range(10):
  test = rd.randrange(-1000, 1000)
  print(test)

# 10 random por class
class NeuralNetwork:
  random = rd.randrange(-1000, 1000)

for n in range(10):
  test = NeuralNetwork()
  print(test.random)
```

fiz ele no repl.it https://repl.it/@nazesaria/AcrobaticImpureBinarysearchtree#main.py

Como posso contorna isso de outra forma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse comportamento ocorre porque você definiu a uma variável de classe `random` como o valor retornado por `rd.randrange(-1000, 1000)` ou seja esse valor será o mesmo para todas as instancias e como é feita apenas uma chamada `rd.randrange(-1000, 1000)` ao definir a classe `NeuralNetwork` ele permanece o mesmo.

Uma solução caso sua intenção seja gerar um valor diferente a cada leitura de `random` seria criar uma propriedade de leitura `random` com o auxilio do decorator [@property](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#property) e fazer com que a cada leitura retorne o valor de `rd.randrange(-1000, 1000)`:

```
import random as rd

class NeuralNetwork:
  
  @property
  def random(self):
      return rd.randrange(-1000, 1000)

test = NeuralNetwork()

for n in range(10):      
  print(test.random)
```

Comment: Tentei aplicar isso na forma que construi, mas infelizmente não estou conseguindo, tentei de varias forma.
Um exemplo mais perto da estrutura q tou usando seria assim https://repl.it/@nazesaria/LawngreenHummingUsers#main.py

Comment: Até deixando essa função a um metodo externo tenho mesmo problema
https://repl.it/@nazesaria/GlossyGigaTrace#main.py

Comment: Não assim que POO funciona, fiz algumas anotações num fork pois o seu código não possui permissão para edição https://repl.it/@RonaldoVasques/LawngreenHummingUsers#main.py . Explique com detalhes o que você está tentando fazer.

Comment: Fiz o código de exemplo para reproduzir o problema, oq estou fazendo é bem simples, fiz um flappy bird(jogo passarinho que fica pulando), e uma rede neural a ele, até ai tudo Ok! 
Agora quero fazer a evolução deles de forma que não seja um "bird" por vez, e sim vários, por isso faço um loop criando vários obj da class Bird, para jogarem simultaneamente.
Problema, quando crio eles todos recebem mesmo valores aleatórios.
Aquilo foi exemplo pra mostra que todos 'obj' na layers[0].weights[0] recebem mesmo peso. Mas queria q cada um viesse diferente.
https://github.com/Pessutto/flappybird_ia

Comment: Entendi. O problema é que você quer que quando imprimir o valor `print(obj.brain.layers[0].weights[0]) ` ele imprima um valor diferente, a linguagem não faz isso. Você definiu um valor para a variável `obj.brain.layers[0].weights[0]` esse valor só se altera se você o redefinir. Se quer que a cada print venha um número novo tem que ler de uma *propriedade* pois essa pode se definir uma função a ser executada a cada leitura.

Comment: Eu modifiquei o https://repl.it/@RonaldoVasques/LawngreenHummingUsers#main.py veja se agora está de acordo com o que você quer?

Comment: Vlw, consegui contorna isso, mas não obtive o sucesso que queria, achei q era esse o problema de aparecer apenas um 'bird' na tela, mas mesmo criando agr varios com weights diferente ainda só aparece um.
de qualquer forma obrigado.